# Dropdown add default name

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown it contain all country names.The code is working fine but I need to add a default choice in the dropdown.How to add a default choice?(<--choose-->).
my code is

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ddlCountryofOrgin.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_DataType_ddlCountryofOrgin" %>
<asp:DropDownList    ID="ddlCountry" CssClass="ddlCountry" runat="server" DataValueField="english_name"
    DataSourceID="sqlCountry" OnPreRender="ddlCountry_PreRender" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" />

<asp:SqlDataSource  ID="sqlCountry" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT [country_id],[english_name], danish_name  FROM [dbo].[nano_country] WHERE [is_active] = 1 ORDER BY [sort_order] DESC, [english_name] ASC" />
```

Thanks in advance for help...

Answer (score 3):

Set `AppendDataBoundItems` as `True`

and add item to dropdownlist:

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">--Choose--</asp:ListItem>
```

Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList    ID="ddlCountry" CssClass="ddlCountry" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems = "True" DataValueField="english_name"
    DataSourceID="sqlCountry" OnPreRender="ddlCountry_PreRender" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" >
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">--Choose--</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, system.EventArgs as e)
{
ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0,"--Choose--");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select","--Choose--")
```